# Path().rglob() hangs script when searching through a large directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

I've noticed that `Path().rglob()` hangs my script after processing if I pass a large directory (or drive in my case). Is there a way to mitigate that?

```
from pathlib import Path

for p in Path('C:\\').rglob('Downloads'):
    print(str(p))
```

The above hangs my script for a few seconds after the search completes and before it prints the results. Anyone have an idea why? Can I eliminate that? If I search a smaller directory, it does not hang.

Answer (score 0):

[The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) specify the following:

> **Note:** Using the “`**`” pattern in large directory trees may consume an inordinate amount of time.

I was using [`rglob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) which

> is like calling [Path.glob()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) with “`**/`” added in front of the
> given relative *pattern*.

My solution (which helps tremendously) is to not search directories with large amounts of subdirectories. i.e. Don't search the "C:\Windows" directory.  Skipping that directory cut the search time by 4.